when trying to sell a token im holding im getting this error, execution reverted: "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" (action="estimateGas",
im new to the bullx platform and im running into this error when trying to sell. execution reverted: "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" (action="estimateGas",. what does this mean?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
